# Load external properties file in a Gradle project which could be used in build files as well as the multi project application

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am currently migrating a Maven project to Gradle and we use the below maven plugin to read an external properties files in Maven project

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${user.home}/my_global.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This plugin reads the external property file and the properties are accessible in pom.xml as well as other Java files.
I am trying to find a similar plugin for Gradle and tried various ways to include the properties file in my project, but I could only find a way to get the details in build.gradle file. Below is an excerpt of what I tried

```
ext.extProgram = new Properties()
extProgram.load(new FileInputStream("${System.properties['user.home']}/my_global.properties"))

project.ext['any.plugin.property']=extProgram['property.in.external.file']
```

I want a way in Gradle such that only reference to my external properties files can allow me to fetch it's key value pairs in build scripts and any Java file.

Comment: Did you find a better solution by now?

Comment: @RanilWijeyratne, I am currently using a java code to read the properties files from `User Home` during app initialization. I am not using Gradle to read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're transitioning from Maven to Gradle, then put similar properties into "~/.gradle/gradle.properties". Read the User Guide in the distro for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I know of this way, but I want to figure out if there's any alternate to it. Meaning, I need to load my properties files the same way as Gradle loads the gradle.properties file.